# How to see other users in indoor location app built on estimote sdk

Tags: estimote, indoor-positioning-system

I have built an indoor location ios app using Estimote SDK and its working fine. Now I want to see all the users in same location to be able to see each other in App.
Any suggestions on how to do that. Please comment and let me know if anything is not clear about the question

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example how we did it using IndoorAtlas & PubNub service. Does not require any logic on the server side and allows you to tap into the location stream from several different types of clients such as mobile or browser. You should be able to do it in similar way using Estimote.

https://github.com/IndoorAtlas/android-sdk-examples/tree/master/Basic/src/main/java/com/indooratlas/android/sdk/examples/sharelocation

Comment: Can you please tell which part of code specifically I should look into?

Comment: This line shares ones location to a PubNub channel to which several clients  may subscribe to: https://github.com/IndoorAtlas/android-sdk-examples/blob/master/Basic/src/main/java/com/indooratlas/android/sdk/examples/sharelocation/channel/pubnub/PubNubLocationChannelImpl.java#L78